# Rails 4 ActiveRecord query join and order by a user's number of association records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models, UserActivity, User, and UserPhoto.

```
User
  has_many :user_photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user_activity, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy

UserActivity
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :user_photos, to: :user

UserPhoto
    belongs_to :user
```

I want to fetch all users that are "active" and have a subscription and order them by the last time they engaged in a "user activity" and order them according to the number of photos they have.

Currenty, I have:

```
UserActivity.where(gender: "M")
            .joins(:user)
            .where("users.activation_state = 'active'")
            .order('user_activities.updated_at DESC')
            .includes([:user, user: [ :subscription ]])
```

This will return all active users sorted by last activity update.

I've tried adding query fragments such as ".joins(:user_photo).order('user.user_photos.length DESC')" which causes the above to choke.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT/Update: I used the counter cache as suggested by the below user and ended up with:

UserActivity.where(gender: "M")
            .joins(:user)
            .where("users.activation_state = 'active'")
            .order('user_activities.updated_at DESC')
            .includes([:user, user: [ :subscription ]]).order('user_photos_count DESC')

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to order by a subquery which retrieves the count of the child records, something like:

```
order("(select count(*) from user_photos where user_photos.user_id = users.id) desc")
```

However maintaining a counter cache for user_photos on the users table would be more efficient.

```
order("user_photos_count desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do:

```
class UserPhoto
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end

class User
  # You need extra column here: user_photos_count

  has_many :user_photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user_activity, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy

  scope :active, -> { where(activation_state: 'active') }
  scope :with_subscription, -> { joins(:subscription) }
end
```

and then simply

```
User.active.with_subscription.joins(:user_activities, :user_photos).order('user_activities.updated_at DESC').order(user_photos_count: desc)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, I started doing this but due to the way the previous person coded it I needed a UserActivity object(s) back - otherwise I would have had to refactor some views.  But I did use the counter caching.